# Can't open app with react-native-app-link

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

I'm trying to open Microsoft Teams and Yammers app if its installed on the users phone if not the user is redirected to the playstore; this is done using **react-native-app-link** which makes this a lot easier and faster.

The issue i am having is that I can't find the name of the apps to open.  ***On Android***

```
 const openApplication = (
url,
appName,
appStoreId,
appStoreLocale,
playStoreId,
 ) => {
 AppLink.maybeOpenURL(url, {
   appName,
   appStoreId,
   appStoreLocale,
   playStoreId,
 });
};

 <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          openApplication(
            'microsoft-teams://', <= does not work, but 'skype://' and 'facebook://'works for example
            'Microsoft Teams',
            '1113153706',
            'pl',
            'com.microsoft.teams',
          )
        }>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

> The first argument is the link to the app on the phone, if its not
> found it uses all the other arguments to link to the playstore to
> enable the user to download the app.

Comment: I don't get your question you already add name of the app (Microsoft Teams). which name are you talking about?
Also why name is so important, I think `react-native-app-link` should be working now.
Let me know your issue.

Comment: @Nitish I'm specifaclly talking about this link "  'microsoft-teams://' '" its not actually opening the microsoft teams app on my phone even tho i have it installed.

As an example i've tried it using facebook app. If i have it installed on my phone it opens up the app, but when i've deleted the app it redirected me to the playstore page.

The issue is that I am not able to open the app even if i have it installed it just takes me to the playstore

Comment: Hi, What you are referring to is the URL field (not name or app name field). you called it as name field. and react-native-app-link using this for opening the app directly but I found it works only with iOS not with Android and I think you describe you have an issue with the Android app only not iOS. So, the android package name should work for you but after I checked the code I found it will directly open the app over play store or browser. 
If that's the case let me know I will create a module for you.